# Configure Akka remote hostname allow both server instance and load balancer DNS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, playframework, akka, elastic-load-balancer

We use simple Akka Remote calls between our EC2 instances that are behind Load balancers.  Each instance type (A and B) are behind load balancers and can have multiple instances, respectively.  We use *tell* to send requests and use getSender() to know who to respond back to, when needed.

I've tried setting `remote.netty.tcp.hostname` to the following configurations, listed with their outcomes:

1. hostname:ServerA-**loadbalancer**-dns:

   - request from ServerA --> ServerB-load-balancer: ServerB responds back to the **ServerA-loadbalancer-dns** allowing the response to be routed to a different instance, one that didn't make the request. Causing a timeout.
   - so the request works, but the response fails
2. hostname:ServerA-**instance**-dns:

   - request from ServerA --> ServerB-load-balancer: ServerB responds back to the **ServerA-instance-dns** which works because it knows exactly who to respond to.
   - request from Server**B** --> Server**A**-load-balancer: fails because the hostname is set to ServerA-**instance**-dns which doesn't match the load balancer used in the request.  Error message:

   > akka.remote.EndpointWriter - dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://application@ServerA-loadbalancer-dns:8000/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://application@ServerA-loadbalancer-dns:8000] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://application@ServerA-instance-dns:8000]

So because I can't allow two acceptable hostnames for my incoming remote calls, I will always have a failure case, with this current setup.  Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: "As explained in that chapter Akka remoting is designed for communication in a peer-to-peer fashion and it has limitations for client-server setups. In particular Akka Remoting does not work transparently with Network Address Translation, Load Balancers, or in Docker containers. " - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/remoting.html

Comment: I am familiar with those docs - I was hoping that I missed something or someone had a different approach.  I also saw this and wondered if there had been any progress: https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/396
Thanks for the response!